# Android Chat Application using Openfire server and XMPP (SMACK) client

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire

So far, I have learnt that I need a Chat Server(Openfire) and a XMPP client with Smack Libraries to communicate with the server.So,

1. Installed and configured Openfire.
2. Now for the client part, I am really confused how to get start with.

I need a simple chat application with limited users and few features like file sharing, message sent and seen, users online etc.

P.S: Yes, I am new to android and have built few applications, but good at UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android chat application using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) using its Google Cloud Connection Server (CSS) via XMPP. Its a very long answer type question. I must suggest you to look here for [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I dont want to use GCM any other suggestions pls.

Comment: yes visit http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/ or http://blog.titechnologies.in/build-a-chat-application-in-android-using-xmpp/ this.. must accept if worked.  :)

Comment: Thanks, that can help me started.

Comment: the tutorial gave me broad understanding about the chat application.

Comment: Actually i came across some opensource xmpp clients which can really solve my purpose like xabber xmpp client and configuring your openfire server, setting up new users in server, adding those details in xabber client solved my purpose.

Comment: https://github.com/siacs/Conversations

Comment: https://github.com/siacs/Conversations nice open source code to start with.

Comment: can you please try here : https://kpblogs.com/mobile-development/android/android-chat-application-using-openfire-server-and-xmpp-smack-client/

Comment: There is a [Course on XMPP and Smack on Android](http://www.blikoontech.com/video-courses/) that covers the details step by step. Disclaimer : I am the author of the course ;-)